# Azure B2C Password Change gives me invalid Username/Password

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to implement a Azure AD B2C Password Change policy for Azure B2C.

I've used [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/change-password/policy/PasswordChange.xml) policy and updated the `client_id`, `resource_id`, `IdTokenAudience` values in the "login-NonInteractive" technical profile accordingly.

When I execute this policy now, then I can log in and change my password afterwards accordingly as expected.

But when I invoke the policy out of the application, where the user is loged in via a standard SignIn Userflow, the login page doesn't show up, I get directly refered to the password change page, and if I enter the old and new password there I get a "The username or password provided in the request are invalid." message.

[image]

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim names between user flow and custom policies are different, so here when it’s trying to verify the old password, the users identifier ends up being null. Use custom policies OR user flows, do not combine.

Comment: Please refer solution mentioned in the github issue - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/173