# Self-service password change gives invalid username or password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to set up a password change flow with a custom policy as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

I've followed the steps and almost got it all to work, when I run the custom policy everything looks fine, I have one input field for the old password and two for the new one. If i run the policy from the Azure portal, or in my application when I'm signed out, I'm first prompted with the sign-in page and afterwards changing the password works fine. However if I'm already signed in I get the error message "Invalid username or password" after filling in the old password and a new one.

The old password is 100% correct (I've tried this several times so no typos, and the password works when signing in). I have another custom policy (change of email-address) that is working just fine.

The initial signin is through a standard "signin" userflow (tried different ones, with and without MFA as well as a unified flow).

Does anyone know what my issue could be or how I can troubleshoot it further?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466539/azure-b2c-password-change-gives-me-invalid-username-password

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT thanks for the reply. It seems to work better when using a custom policy to sign in. However I'm having trouble activating TOTP with my custom policy. Could you have a look at my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576057/bad-request-when-trying-to-get-available-strong-authentication-devices