# Bad request when trying to get available strong authentication devices

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to setup a signin-flow with custom policys that supports TOTP. I used the instructions provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy and made the necessary edits to my TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS-file.

However when I try out the policy I'm immediately returned to my website after submitting an email and password.

After checking the Audit log I can see a ClientError with activity type "Get available strong authentication devices" and status reason "The service received a bad request"

The technical profile for this request looks like this

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureMfa-GetAvailableDevices">
   <DisplayName>Get Available Devices</DisplayName>
   <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureMfaProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
   <Metadata>
      <Item Key="Operation">GetAvailableDevices</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
   </InputClaims>
   <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="numberOfAvailableDevices" />
   </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

and the orchestraction step

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
         <Value>newUser</Value>
         <Value>True</Value>
         <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
   </Preconditions>
   <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckAvailableDevices" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AzureMfa-GetAvailableDevices" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Is there an obvious error I'm making or are there any tips on how I can troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out this issue? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Julian.Net unfortunately I can't really remember what we did to solve this, there where so many issues for us implementing custom policys with Azure AD B2C. In the end though, we opted to only use phone number for 2fa and skip TOTP altogether.

Comment: thank you. Yeah, TOTP has been challenging and still have not figured it out. Phone MFA seems to be working though.

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting with Application Insights led me to the solution.

I found this error in the logs:

```
A partner claim with id 'userPrincipalName' is not found however is required in technical profile 'AzureMfa-GetAvailableDevices'
```

So I forgot to alter a TechnicalProfile in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- The userPrincipalName is required for the AzureMfaProtocolProvider technical profiles-->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Enabling Application Insights in Azure B2C (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights):

- Create an Application Insights instance in the main tenant (not in B2C tenant)
- Note down the Instrumentation Key (Configure - Properties)

Add two extra attributes to <TrustFrameworkPolicy> in SignIn.xml:

```
  DeploymentMode="Development"
  UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights"
```

And add <JourneyInsights> to the <UserJourneyBehaviors> in SignIn.xml

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant"/>
    <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
    <SessionExpiryInSeconds>43200</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
    <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Settings:InsightsInstrumentationKey}" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="true" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Reupload and retry the policy. Search in Application Insights (query traces) for those events.